# Php Messagebox (sever-side) Help in any way please

Tags: php, client, server-side, messagebox

I need help to display a messagebox within the Php code I been using.

the code is down below:

```
    if (!isset($_POST['q']) || empty($_POST['q'])) {
    die('Please Enter a Keyword to Search For.');

    } else {
    $q = $_POST['q'];
    $q = ereg_replace('[[:space:]]+', '/', trim($q));
    }
```

-Some references to the code
  'q' is the search term entered 
  the code after "} else {" is just trimming down white space in the keyword and etc/

I want it to display and say "Please Enter a Keyword to Search For"
at the moment I have looked at multiple forums and pages and failed.

The code above just display the error message on a different page but 
I want it to be displayed on the same page for more of a beneficently way of doing it.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: You'll want to use Javascript for basic clientside form validation like this: put some JS code (plenty of examples on Google) on the page with the form and then you can always doublecheck in the PHP script on the second page

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using JavaScript.

Replace google.com with your error page URL.

```
<?php
if (!isset($_POST['q']) || empty($_POST['q'])) {
    //die('Please Enter a Keyword to Search For.');
    echo "<script>alert('Please Enter a Keyword to Search For.')</script>";
echo "<script>document.location.href='http://www.google.com'</script>";

    } else {
    $q = $_POST['q'];
    $q = ereg_replace('[[:space:]]+', '/', trim($q));
    }

?>
```

Comment: I tried that but after I hit 'OK" it redirect to a HTTP Error page.              "failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request"

Comment: Seems like you are not showing your full code ;) . Anyone could try that example and there is no chance for 400 httpstatusCode. Can you post your full code ?

Comment: for certain reasons I can't Show my full code.  All i need help with is the messagebox I found other way of the JS code to display but they all after I enter goes straight to the Http failure page.

Comment: but also some way i did just show a new page and show "Please enter a keyword to search for"

Comment: I have edited the code, replace the URL with your error page.

Comment: well, atm im using apache as a 'localhost' and the website is not published atm so all it shows is 'localhost'          it mentions something about  simplexml_load_file

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood your problem correctly. But if you want to display the error on the same page (not on another page) just replace:

```
die('Please Enter a Keyword to Search For.');
```

with:

```
echo 'Please Enter a Keyword to Search For.';
```

If you want to be redirected to another page just use the header function:

```
header('Location: example.php');
```

And write the error message in that file instead.